# How to convert mouseover and mouseout functionality to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert this functionality from mouseover and mouseout to click event below is the code.

```
var IdAry=['slide2','slide3','slide4','slide5','slide8','slide9','slide12','slide13','slide14','slide15','slide16'];
window.onload=function() {
 for (var zxc0=0;zxc0<IdAry.length;zxc0++){
  var el=document.getElementById(IdAry[zxc0]);
  if (el){
   el.onmouseover=function() {
     changeText(this,'hide','show')
    }
   el.onmouseout=function() {
     changeText(this,'show','hide');
    }
  }
 }
}
function changeText(obj,cl1,cl2) {
   obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className=cl1;
   obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className=cl2;
}
```

and below is the HTML part

```
<div id="graphics">
                    <img src="images/circle-bg.jpg" alt="" class="circleBg"/>
                    <div class="row1">
                        <a href="#" id="slide1" id="selectedSlide">
                            <span id="span1"></span>
                            <span class="hide"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="slide2">
                            <span id="span1"></span>
                            <span class="hide">At this stage, we sit down together and discuss your life goals and begin to develop a plan for funding them. Without knowing where you want to go, we can't help get you there! This is the time to ask a lot of questions and get to know each other. </span>                      
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="slide3">
                            <span id="span1"></span>
                            <span class="hide">We need to know your current income and expenses in order to gain a better understanding of resources that can be applied toward your financial goals. We also determine the appropriate size of your emergency fund. </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="slide4">
                            <span id="span1"></span>
                            <span class="hide"></span>                      
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Currently when user mouseover anchor tag of id slide1, slide2, slide3.. etc it added class show to one span and hide to other and vice versa in mouseout.

So if is possible to convert this functionality to click event instead of mouseover and mouseout.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You tagged this as jQuery, but your code is pure JavaScript. Do you want a jQuery solution or a equivalent in pure JS? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to toggle with each click.

Here I do the handler assignment in a separate function, so that each handler can have access to its own local variables.

Then I put the `"show"` and `"hide"` in an Array within that function, and on each click the Array is reversed, and passed to `changeText` using `.apply` to invoke it.

```
var IdAry = ['slide2', 'slide3', 'slide4', 'slide5', 'slide8', 'slide9', 'slide12', 'slide13', 'slide14', 'slide15', 'slide16'];
window.onload = function () {
    for (var zxc0 = 0; zxc0 < IdAry.length; zxc0++) {
        var el = document.getElementById(IdAry[zxc0]);
        if (el) {
            setUpHandler(el);
        }
    }
}

function setUpHandler(el) {
    var state = ["show", "hide"];

    el.onclick = function () {
        changeText.apply(this, this, state.reverse());
    }
    el = null;
}

function changeText(obj, cl1, cl2) {
    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className = cl1;
    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className = cl2;
}
```

---

If you don't like the idea of reversing a short Array each click, then you could do this instead...

```
function setUpHandler(el) {
    var ab = true;

    el.onclick = function () {
        ab = !ab
        changeText(this, 
                   ab ? "show" : "hide", 
                   ab ? "hide" : "show");
    }
    el = null;
}

function changeText(obj, cl1, cl2) {
    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className = cl1;
    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className = cl2;
}
```

---

Or since you tagged jQuery, you could do this...

```
$("#" + IdAry.join(",#")).toggle(function() { changeText(this, "hide", "show"); }),
                                 function() { changeText(this, "show", "hide"); }));
```

---

```
var prev;

function changeText(obj, cl1, cl2) {

    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className = cl1;
    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className = cl2;

    if (prev && obj !== prev) {
        prev.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className = "";
        prev.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className = "";
    }
    prev = obj
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks dude your logic is perfect but still we have to add one more thing into it like.

One:When page load there were no classes which is correct
Two:In second case when i click on any of the anchor tag then it apply the correct classes, then afterwards when i again click on next tag it is not removing previous classes from previous clicked tag

So could you help me out in removing previous click classes from span?

Comment: These classes should be applied only to clicked one but it should be removed from previous one, I think you got my point

Comment: @SushilRaghav: See the update to the `changeText` function at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @SushilRaghav: My original update had a mistake. Are you using the current version in my answer?

Comment: Sir below is the code i am using
$("#" + IdAry.join(",#")).toggle(function() { changeText(this, "hide", "show"); }),
                                 function() { changeText(this, "show", "hide"); }));

Comment: @SushilRaghav: I mean the `changeText` function that I added to the bottom of my answer. Are you using that?

Comment: Sir: now its working fine i am very closer to my target thanks a lot sir below is the little change in code 
function changeText(obj, cl1, cl2) {

    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className = "hide";
    obj.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className = "show";

    if (prev && obj !== prev) {
        prev.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].className = "";
        prev.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[1].className = "hide";
    }
    prev = obj
}

Comment: Hi, I have created this functionality for this page [http://ivyfa.advisorproducts.com/financial-planning-process] but still i am facing little bit problem in this -> After page load when you click on any of the text like Cash flow analysis, tax analysis, investment analysis etc which in rounded colured boxed you will seen some text in center with read more link which is not clickable but still its showing link on hover but its not opening page may be due to show hide code in js please help me :) I want to make Read more link clickable.